# Entity Framework Lined Tables not first or default

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have below query.

```
Dim p = From it In LiveRmis.product_detail
        Where it.POS_CODE = Barcode And it.WHL_SKU_LOCATION.FirstOrDefault.WHL_LEVEL_DETAIL.WHL_CODE_CHAIN.Contains("KIN")
        Select it
```

What happens if my result is not the first or default line in WHL_SKU_LOCATION? If I remove the firstordefault param then I do not have access to the following linked table.

Will this basically loop through the possible lines in WHL_LEVEL_DETAIL until it finds a code chain that contains KIN or just return not found?

Is this the correct way to even do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do?
It seems that your product detail has multiple WHL_SKULOCATION's
and that your WHL_SKULOCATION has 1 WHL_LEVEL_DETAIL.
If you want to get a product_detail that has at least 1 WHL_SKULOCATION with the "KIN" chain you could write your statement like this :

```
Dim p = From it In LiveRmis.product_detail
        Where it.POS_CODE = Barcode 
        And it.WHL_SKU_LOCATION.Any(wsl=> wsl.WHL_LEVEL_DETAIL.WHL_CODE_CHAIN.Contains("KIN")
        Select it
```

Note that the firstOrDefault you're using has no condition (like firstOrDefault(t=>t.ID=1)) so it will really give you the first found WHL_SKU_LOCATION.
If you should only have 1 WHL_SKU_LOCATION for every product_detail then you need to fix your data context to represent this.

Comment: Thanks @Kristof - You are correct, however the powers that be have decided that our company requires a second warehouse, of which the system was never designed to handle, stock can be in both warehouses at the same time is my main issue, but this helped me along the way